# Firebase authentication persistence across two web apps

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a platform which consists of a public facing 'website' and a PWA which will be on a subdomain on the same server.

Both web apps use the same firebase project and I was wondering if it is possible to share authentication status between the two. i.e. can I redirect a user to the PWA side without them having to login again?

Both apps are written with React, Redux and Node

Answer (score 1):

Store the authentication token in a cookie with the following domain:

`.mydomain.com`

where mydomain.com is the public site. Now the PWA can access this cookie as a subdomain of mydomain.com.

Subdomains can not access localstorage of the main domain or other subdomains, but can access cookies in the main domain.

If Firebase automatically writes to localstorage, write your own code to delete it from there (or leave it there), and add it as a cookie.

I don't think you need to put the `.` in front of the domain for your cookie anymore, but you used to and I still do.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the reply, I'll give this a try asap and report back!